# Difference between two types of jQuery AJAX call with type:'GET' and type:'POST'?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

I have seen different types of jQuery AJAX call with `type:'GET'` and `type:'POST'` with PHP Mysqli Programming but i have doubt :-

So when and Where we used these two different type , i mean in which scenario we are use `type:'GET'` and `type:'POST'` with PHP Mysqli like these:-

Is there any technical difference between both of them?

**type:"GET"**

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"action.php",
    data:{key:val},
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
   }
});
```

**type:"POST"**

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"action.php",
    data:{key:val},
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: who has down vote my question , what is the problem in that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods

Comment: @KUMAR, problem is that's very simple question, and in first step, you should use Google. FYI: that wasn't me who downvoated.

Comment: @biesior ok sir , i am not asking its you but i have confused in that. i want to know the answer properly with ajax jquery php call.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of information about GET vs POST request, as it's one of the oldest topics on the internet: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

In general, for security reasons, it's always better to use POST over the GET.

In AJAX requests difference is the same.

Use Inspector in your browser and navigate to Network tab, to validate that:

[image: Screenshot for AJAX request in Network inspection]

Comment: It's also one of the oldest questions on SO... https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=GET+vs+POST

Comment: @freedomn-m point for you ;)

Comment: @freedomn-m  sir i know the difference between `POST & GET` in `<form>` Tag but i am  asking in ajax calls with type.

Comment: @KUMAR, the rules are the same for common form and AJAX, the difference is between methods how they are sent to the server.

Comment: @biesior ok sir thanks.

Comment: @freedomn-m  ok sir thanks.

Comment: @freedomn-m  sir so what is the difference is between methods?

Comment: @KUMAR, use inspector tools, you'll see they behave the same as within GET/POST form.

Comment: @ biesior ok sir thanks for your guidance.